# When i require ngModel controller how do I access a property of the model controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I am using `ng-repeat` and setting a model with it similar to the following

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-model="thing"  my-directive>
    {{thing.name}}
</div>
```

then in my directive it looks something like this

```
.directive("myDirective, function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, lElement, attrs, model) {

         console.log(model.name);// this gives me 'NAN'
        }
    }
})
```

My question is how can I access the values in the model? I tried `model.$modelValue.name` but that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind in a scoped value then you can use the '=' in an isolated.  This will appear on the scope of your directive.  To read the `ng-model` directive, you can use `=ngModel`:

```
.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        }
        link: function(scope) {

         console.log(scope.model.name); // will log "thing"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, lElement, attrs, model) {

         console.log(attrs.ngModel); // will log "thing"
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your directive does not have isolated or child scope then you can do this:

```
.directive('someDirective', function() {
    return {
        require: ['^ngModel'],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0];
            var someVal;
            // you have to implement $render method before you can get $viewValue
            ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
                someVal = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
            };
            // and to change ngModel use $setViewValue
                    // if doing it in event handler then scope needs to be applied
            element.on('click', function() {
                var val = 'something';
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(val);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```